# struct entry: Manual command line access?

Tags: objective-c, command-line, argv, argc

how does this code work: more precisely the line that passes the struct into the command line agc and argv ? what is it doing? Is there another way to do this?

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

      int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

        struct entry dictionary[100] =
{   { "aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"  } ,
    { "abyss", "a bottomless pit' } ,  
    { "acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"
    { "addle",  "to become confused" } , 
    { "aerie", "a high nest" }, 
    { "affix","to append, attach" },
    { "agar"," a jelly made from seaweed" }, 
    { "ahoy"," a nautical call of greeting"  }, 
    { "aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers" } , 
    { "ajar", "partially opened" }        } ;

      int entries = 10;
       int entryNumber;
      int lookup (struct entry dictionary [], char search[],
      int entries); 

if ( argc != 2 ) {
    NSLog (@"No word typed on the command line.");
        return (1); }
   entryNumber = lookup (dictionary, argv[1], entries);
     if ( entryNumber != -1 )
     NSLog (@"%s", dictionary[entryNumber].definition);
     else
   NSLog (@"Sorry, %s is not in my dictionary.", argv[1]);
       return (0); }
```

Comment: No struct is pass into the command line. The argument passed on the command line (if any) is used to lookup a value inside the struct.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, so strictly speaking it doesn't "work" at all.

Comment: Since you do not understand this code I assume you didn't write this. Can't you ask the person who did write this to explain it to you?

Comment: This is code for code out of the objective c 6th edition book pg.301. Its used to pass in arguments into the command line.. so it says.